# Event when all markers for Angular Google Maps makers have been drawn

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Im currently using the Angular Google Maps lib (http://angular-google-maps.org/), have an application that makes a request for data that is plotted as markers (this happens long after the map has been drawn). However this data set is large and it takes some time for all the markers to have been drawn on the map. Is there a way to catch an event or watch for when all the markers have been drawn e.g. to allow for a spinner to be shown while the markers are being drawn. I have already looked at the events such as idle however this only accounts for pan and zoom. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by listing to the DOMNodeInserted on the .angular-google-map-container element, this fires when the markers have been drawn on the map